# How to create a custom mixin in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a decorator which prevents the user from accessing URLs if the product with `id=1` is not activated.

I want to create a mixin similar to this.

This is my decorator:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from ecommerce_integration.models import Product 


def product_1_activation(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        products = Product.objects.filter(pk=1, activate=True)
        if products:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

Any idea how to create a custom mixin similar to the above decorator?

Actually I want to create mixins for my Class Based View.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Can you share your view too?

Comment: You mean the views where I want to put my mixins?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We can make a `Mixin` that just overrides the `dispatch` method, like:

```
class ProductExistsRequiredMixin:

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if Product.objects.filter(pk=1, activate=True):
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
```

and then use it in a view like:

```
class MyCustomView(ProductExistsRequiredMixin, View):

    # ...
```

Comment: I don't understand who "super()" is since ProductExistsRequiredMixin doesn't inherit from anything?

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions: the next item in the MRO. So if we in the `MyCustomView` inherit from `ProductExistsRequiredMixin`, and `View`, then that will be the `dispatch` of the `View`. But if we inherit from another sort of view that overrides the `dispatch`, then that will be the first item in the MRO.

Comment: *Facepalm* yes that makes lots of sense. Outside of django, haven't used multiple inheritence much since I was always told it is the demon. Thanks.